# What are the absolute and relative costs of different operations in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, architecture

I'm looking for a elaborate list comparing different operations in PHP. For example: echo vs. printf, ++$i vs $i++, a direct function call vs. object function call, array access vs. direct data access, global vs. local variables, mysql_fetch_assoc vs. mysql_fetch_row etc. Of course these figures probably highly depend on the used version, the OS, hardware and many other factors, but I saw lists like this for c/c++ and maybe there is something similar for PHP.

**Update**

Will leave this question open for two more days. Maybe we can get a few more of these usefull links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you with some of the functions/operators: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: Sorry for the late response still browsing the site. NICE find and thanks for sharing! As far as I can tell they lack a few things, but nevertheless it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! Some days ago, [this article at google code](http://code.google.com/intl/es/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html) appeared on just this subject. It was refuted almost immediately by [this refutation](http://groups.google.com/group/make-the-web-faster/browse_thread/thread/ddfbe82dd80408cc). So watch out and **test everytime**.

Answer (score 1):

["The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28computer_science%29#Quotes)- Michael A. Jackson

Answer (score 0):

why not run a few tests yourself comparing them? That way you know that for a machine with X specs runs echo at Y time whilst it does printf at Z time?

Comment: Good point and I totally agree that it could give me a very clear picture for my equipment. However I also want to get a more broader view on these things (relative figures) in comparison with other OS/hardware. One more thing: With my lack of knowledge about the PHP architecture I don't think that I could come up with very good test-cases.

Answer (score 0):

“We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." Donald Knuth.

The thing I like the most about this statement: Note that he says "small efficiencies". He's talking about code tuning... Essentially, I think he's arguing for getting your algorithm right from the beginning, but saving the code tuning for only when it's absolutely necessary.